# Finding height of rope when at an angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, potential-energy

The question is that Jeff swings on a 7.6m rope that initially makes an angle of 37° with the vertical. If Jeff starts at rest and has a mass of 78kg, what is the tension in the vine at the lowest point of the swing?

I know to start solving this by setting the initial mechanical equal to the final and in this case we start with only a kinetic and end with only a potential gravitational:

$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = mgy$

In the solution they say $y = (L-Lcos(37))$ why is that the case in this instance?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for “check my work” problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic). You might get a better response at a more appropriate site.  [Here’s one to consider.](http://www.physicsforums.com), but there are others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the diagram.  His path is the arc of a circle centered on the pivot.  Draw the horizontal from the starting point to the vertical and you have a right triangle.